# Auto zoom to the user location in JotForm

Tags: javascript, zooming

I am using Google Map JavaScript API in third party form (Jotform), which I embed in my website. I want the map to detect the user location and automatically zoom to this location. Now It zooms to a different location when I try on my pc. I am not a professional developer but using third-party solutions.

Comment: You won't be able to localize the user's location always reliable. Often the location of the Internet provider is shown, or of a node of it's network. It doesn't matter about the detailed reasons, just it's not always the user's detailed location.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to add current location of the user to form. Rather than using google map API you can easily implement the location into the form. If you would like your user to be able to provide you with their current location (if only user enable geolocation service), you can use JotForm Widgets such as address_map_locator or show_map_location. This would allow your user to enter their address and it would be displayed on Google Maps. I hope this helps

Comment: Thank you, I will try it and come back to you

Comment: Happy to help. If this answer or any other one solved your issue, please mark it as accepted.